# Pulling docker image from private repository

Tags: github-package-registry

Is it possible to pull image from a private repository without adding someone to that repository? I am trying to see if I can enable someone just to pull packages/images in a repo without having read access to the code in github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I reached out to Github support and this is the current recommendation

https://github.community/t/token-with-repo-scope-to-install-private-packages/119932/2